# Why Python repo is not installed in WSL?

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

From my WSL terminal

```
pip install schemathesis
Requirement already satisfied: schemathesis in /home/milenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.9.7)
Requirement already satisfied: hypothesis_jsonschema>=0.20.1 in /home/milenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from schemathesis) (0.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.22 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from schemathesis) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytest>4.6.4 in /home/milenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from schemathesis) (6.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytest-subtests<1.0,>=0.2.1 in /home/milenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from schemathesis) (0.5.0)
```

When I try

```
:/mnt/c/Users/v-mimaholmes$ schemathesis
```

I got

```
schemathesis: command not found
```

If I try what Tzane suggested

```
 python3 -m schemathesis
/usr/bin/python3: No module named schemathesis.__main__; 'schemathesis' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Outout from pip freeze

```
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
schemathesis==3.9.7
SecretStorage==2.3.1
```

Why?

I do not have .local/lib.

Comment: Is it possible that the directory in which the `schemathesis` executable was placed is not in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @Shinratensei I do not know where is schemathesis.

Comment: Then I suppose you should try and find it because it has to be somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WSL the install location for the schemathesis -script is not in `$PATH` as Shinra tensei correctly assumed. I tried installing it myself on WSL Ubuntu and got the following:

```
 The script schemathesis is installed in '/home/taneli/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

and got the same error as you. After adding `~/.local/bin` to `$PATH` it now works as intended:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin`

Not a linux wizard so I followed this about the appending to `$PATH`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059